# Output of variables of the hadoop program with the help of log4j

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, log4j, mapreduce

I wrote hadoop the program with log4j use (only Map step which operation didn't meet my waitings)

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

public class ParallelIndexation {
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private final static LongWritable zero = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Map.class.getName());
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
            DOMConfigurator.configure("/folder/log4j.xml");
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            Path localPath = new Path("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input/paths.txt");
            Path hdfsPath=new Path("hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/user/hadoop/paths.txt");
            Path localPath1 = new Path("/usr/countcomputers.txt");                
            Path hdfsPath1=new Path("hdfs://192.168.1.8:7000/user/hadoop/countcomputers.txt");
            if (!fs.exists(hdfsPath))
            {
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath, hdfsPath);
            };
            if (!fs.exists(hdfsPath1))
            {
                fs.copyFromLocalFile(localPath1, hdfsPath1);
            };          
            FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(hdfsPath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = br.readLine();
            BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(hdfsPath1)));
            int CountComputers;
            String result=br1.readLine();
            CountComputers=Integer.parseInt(result);
            ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                paths.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
            }
            for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++)
                {
                    logger.debug("paths[i]=" + paths.get(i) + "\n");    
                }
            logger.debug("CountComputers=" + CountComputers + "\n");
```

I provide the /folder/log4j.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%-5p][%-16.16t][%32.32c] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

But despite an output in a log, as a result of command execution

```
./hadoop jar /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/ParallelIndexation.jar org.myorg.ParallelIndexation /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/input /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/output -D mapred.map.tasks=1 1> resultofexecute.txt 2>&1
```

in the resultofexecute.txt file there was no output of appropriate variables.Help to remove the necessary variables.
@ChrisWhite I provide the `hadoop-hadoop-tasktracker-myhost2.log` and `hadoop-hadoop-takstacker-myhost3.log` files

`hadoop-hadoop-tasktracker-myhost2.log`

```
2013-04-20 12:35:43,465 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-04-20 12:35:43,583 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:43,584 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:43,584 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
2013-04-20 12:35:43,971 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:43,979 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-04-20 12:35:44,168 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-04-20 12:35:44,251 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-04-20 12:35:44,280 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2013-04-20 12:35:44,287 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tasktracker with owner as hadoop
2013-04-20 12:35:44,288 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Good mapred local directories are: /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local
2013-04-20 12:35:44,302 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-04-20 12:35:44,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:44,312 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source TaskTrackerMetrics registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:49,332 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort51172 registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:49,332 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort51172 registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:49,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:51172
2013-04-20 12:35:49,335 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tracker tracker_myhost2:localhost/127.0.0.1:51172
2013-04-20 12:35:49,356 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-04-20 12:35:49,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,357 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 51172: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,358 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 51172: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,358 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 51172: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,358 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 51172: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,358 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 51172: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:50,372 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:51,372 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:52,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:53,376 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:54,377 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:55,377 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:56,379 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:57,380 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:58,381 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:59,381 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:59,385 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-04-20 12:36:01,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:02,387 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:03,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:04,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:05,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:06,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:07,390 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:08,390 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:09,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:10,392 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:10,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-04-20 12:36:12,393 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:43,011 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
2013-04-20 12:36:43,030 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting thread: Map-events fetcher for all reduce tasks on tracker_myhost2:localhost/127.0.0.1:51172
2013-04-20 12:36:43,031 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid is not available on this machine. So not using it.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2013-04-20 12:36:43,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,182 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: ProcessTree implementation is missing on this system. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: IndexCache created with max memory = 10485760
2013-04-20 12:36:43,214 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ShuffleServerMetrics registered.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50060 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,218 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-04-20 12:36:43,611 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,611 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: FILE_CACHE_SIZE for mapOutputServlet set to : 2000
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304112319_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304070459_0003 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304070459_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304112319_0007 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304070413_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304121018_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:36:43,635 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304192207_0003 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003186
2013-04-20 12:49:24,662 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2013-04-20 12:49:24,665 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0 which needs 1 slots
2013-04-20 12:49:24,665 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0 which needs 1 slots
2013-04-20 12:49:25,006 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer: Initializing user hadoop on this TT.
2013-04-20 12:49:25,377 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-1899194781
2013-04-20 12:49:25,378 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-1899194781 spawned.
2013-04-20 12:49:25,381 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201304201135_0001/attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0/taskjvm.sh
2013-04-20 12:49:26,284 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-1899194781 given task: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0
2013-04-20 12:49:29,803 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0 0.0% setup
2013-04-20 12:49:29,806 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0 is done.
2013-04-20 12:49:29,807 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0  was -1
2013-04-20 12:49:29,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2013-04-20 12:49:29,947 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-1899194781 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2013-04-20 12:49:30,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2013-04-20 12:49:30,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
2013-04-20 12:49:30,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
2013-04-20 12:49:30,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received KillTaskAction for task: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0
2013-04-20 12:49:30,719 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: About to purge task: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0
2013-04-20 12:49:30,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: Map ID attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000001_0 not found in cache
2013-04-20 12:49:30,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201304201135_0001_r_-1899194781
2013-04-20 12:49:30,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201304201135_0001_r_-1899194781 spawned.
2013-04-20 12:49:30,745 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201304201135_0001/attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0/taskjvm.sh
2013-04-20 12:49:31,611 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201304201135_0001_r_-1899194781 given task: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0
2013-04-20 12:49:33,219 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% 
2013-04-20 12:49:33,226 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% 
2013-04-20 12:49:33,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 is in commit-pending, task state:COMMIT_PENDING
2013-04-20 12:49:33,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 0.0% 
2013-04-20 12:49:33,731 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received commit task action for attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0
2013-04-20 12:49:35,143 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 1.0% reduce > reduce
2013-04-20 12:49:35,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0 is done.
2013-04-20 12:49:35,147 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0  was -1
2013-04-20 12:49:35,155 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2013-04-20 12:49:35,272 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201304201135_0001_r_-1899194781 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2013-04-20 12:49:36,775 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2013-04-20 12:49:36,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
2013-04-20 12:49:36,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 2 and trying to launch attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
2013-04-20 12:49:36,783 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received KillTaskAction for task: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0
2013-04-20 12:49:36,784 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: About to purge task: attempt_201304201135_0001_r_000000_0
2013-04-20 12:49:36,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-653215379
2013-04-20 12:49:36,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-653215379 spawned.
2013-04-20 12:49:36,814 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201304201135_0001/attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0/taskjvm.sh
2013-04-20 12:49:37,718 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-653215379 given task: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0
2013-04-20 12:49:38,227 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 0.0% 
2013-04-20 12:49:41,232 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 0.0% cleanup
2013-04-20 12:49:41,238 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 0.0% cleanup
2013-04-20 12:49:41,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 is done.
2013-04-20 12:49:41,243 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0  was -1
2013-04-20 12:49:41,245 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2013-04-20 12:49:41,378 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201304201135_0001_m_-653215379 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2013-04-20 12:49:42,821 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received 'KillJobAction' for job: job_201304201135_0001
2013-04-20 12:49:42,822 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: Map ID attempt_201304201135_0001_m_000000_0 not found in cache
2013-04-20 12:49:42,826 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304201135_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573782822
```

`hadoop-hadoop-tasktracker-myhost3.log`

```
2013-04-20 12:35:43,798 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
2013-04-20 12:35:44,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:44,207 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-04-20 12:35:44,382 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-04-20 12:35:44,467 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-04-20 12:35:44,496 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2013-04-20 12:35:44,500 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tasktracker with owner as hadoop
2013-04-20 12:35:44,501 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Good mapred local directories are: /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local
2013-04-20 12:35:44,506 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-04-20 12:35:44,520 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:44,521 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source TaskTrackerMetrics registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:49,567 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort39327 registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:49,568 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort39327 registered.
2013-04-20 12:35:49,575 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:39327
2013-04-20 12:35:49,575 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tracker tracker_myhost3:localhost/127.0.0.1:39327
2013-04-20 12:35:49,586 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2013-04-20 12:35:49,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 39327: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 39327: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 39327: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 39327: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:49,587 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 39327: starting
2013-04-20 12:35:50,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:51,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:52,618 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:53,618 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:54,619 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:55,619 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:56,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:57,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:58,621 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:59,622 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:35:59,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-04-20 12:36:01,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:02,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 1 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:03,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 2 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:04,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 3 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:05,624 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 4 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:06,625 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 5 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:07,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 6 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:08,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 7 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:09,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 8 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:10,628 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 9 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:10,629 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC: Server at 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001 not available yet, Zzzzz...
2013-04-20 12:36:12,629 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 192.168.1.8/192.168.1.8:7001. Already tried 0 time(s).
2013-04-20 12:36:42,982 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
2013-04-20 12:36:43,000 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting thread: Map-events fetcher for all reduce tasks on tracker_myhost3:localhost/127.0.0.1:39327
2013-04-20 12:36:43,002 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid is not available on this machine. So not using it.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,002 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
2013-04-20 12:36:43,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,157 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: ProcessTree implementation is missing on this system. TaskMemoryManager is disabled.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,165 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache: IndexCache created with max memory = 10485760
2013-04-20 12:36:43,173 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ShuffleServerMetrics registered.
2013-04-20 12:36:43,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() returned 50060 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,176 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-04-20 12:36:43,567 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50060
2013-04-20 12:36:43,567 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: FILE_CACHE_SIZE for mapOutputServlet set to : 2000
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304060623_0002 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304060623_0005 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304070459_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304030513_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304070413_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304012201_0015 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304192207_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304121018_0003 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,576 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304112319_0001 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304112319_0005 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:36:43,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.UserLogCleaner: Adding job_201304070459_0003 for user-log deletion with retainTimeStamp:1366573003161
2013-04-20 12:49:45,627 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received 'KillJobAction' for job: job_201304201135_0001
2013-04-20 12:49:45,628 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Unknown job job_201304201135_0001 being deleted.
```

Answer (score 2):

Log4j output will be written to the task log for each map / reduce task - this doesn't make its way back to the job client std out / err unless a map / reduce task fails in some way.

You'll need to find the task instance via the job tracker, and then view the logs for a particular map / reduce task instance.

Comment: You want to tell, what Log4j realizes an output in any of the hadoop-hadoop-tasktracker-myhost2.log and hadoop-hadoop-takstacker-myhost3.log files @ChrisWhite?